# Copy selected row from a table to another table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add rows selected with checkboxes from one table to other using jquery. This is in my js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#schedule tr input:checkbox").click(function() {
        $('#results tbody').append($(this).parent('tr').clone());
        $(this).parent('tr').remove();
    }); 
});
```

Results are the table where the selected row is supposed to be copied to and the schedule is the source table. Is this how it's done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really a DataTables question. Could you remove the tag, please? If it were the answer would be different. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over complicating it a little bit.

**To move the row(s):**

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on("click","#submit",function(){
      var getSelectedRows = $(".src-table input:checked").parents("tr");

      $(".target-table tbody").append(getSelectedRows);
  })
})
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/PantsStatusZero/pmdna965/

**To copy the row(s):**

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on("click","#submit",function(){
      var getSelectedRows = $(".src-table input:checked").parents("tr").clone();

      $(".target-table tbody").append(getSelectedRows);
  })
})
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/PantsStatusZero/5oomb22d/

Comment: this seems to work, but how can i  copy without deleting from the first table?

Comment: I updated my answer, but pretty much you just add .clone().